# How to pass information about the field data type to the frontend when using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Am using django rest framework 3.6

The frontend library I am using is `x-editable`, it requires knowledge of the datatype of the field.

I am currently fetching my data using Django Rest Framework and Serializers. I have googled about Serializer Field but I have difficulty understanding if it fits my requirements. Also I have no idea how to go about testing if it fits.

Basically I have a endpoint that attempts to fetch a single instance of SomeModel and its 5 related models. `/api/v1.0/shape/2508`

This works okay and I get back a data structure that's like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "art_numbers": [],
        "collection": "",
        "extra_number": "",
        "some_related_model1": {
            "finished_capacity": null,
            "finished_weight": null,
            "finished_width": null,
            "id": 3
        },
        "has_associated_product_variant": false,
        "id": 2508,
        "another_related_model": {
            "bar_height": null,
            "bar_number": "",
            "id": 3,

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way for django restframework to also pass in some metadata about the related model fields? like data type?

The minimum I am looking for is to be able to get back the data type of the fields inside the related models.

I want to be able to detect numbers, normal charfield, textfield

Comment: type for another_related_model or type for every field,which format is your wish?

Comment: updated my question. basically at the least i am looking to discover the datatype for the fields inside all the related models so that my frontend library can respond accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django Rest Framework has [metadata 
 classes.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/) But you can [augment it with another library](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#drf-schema-adapter) called [drf-schema-adapte](http://drf-schema-adapter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_auto_endpoint/metadata/#the-metadata-classes-and-mixin)r.

1. pip install drf-schema-adapter which should be 0.9.43
2. go to settings.py and add this `'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'drf_auto_endpoint.metadata.AutoMetadata',` to your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings
3. add in this brand new setting `DRF_AUTO_METADATA_ADAPTER = 'drf_auto_endpoint.adapters.ReactJsonSchemaAdapter'` in the same file

It should look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'drf_auto_endpoint.metadata.AutoMetadata',
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'SEARCH_PARAM': 'q'
}

DRF_AUTO_METADATA_ADAPTER = 'drf_auto_endpoint.adapters.ReactJsonSchemaAdapter'
```

Choosing ReactJsonSchemaAdapter is a purely personal preference. You can also stick with the SimpleMetadata from DRF itself.

use something like postman to test on the same url but using OPTIONS as the method

You should get back something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Shape Detail",
        "description": "Retrieve a shape by its id.",
        "renders": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "parses": [
            "application/json",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "multipart/form-data"
        ],
        "actions": {
            "PUT": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": true,
                    "label": "ID"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": true,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape Name",
                    "max_length": 100
                },
                "name_en": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape Name [en]",
                    "max_length": 100
                },
                "name_zh_hans": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape Name [zh-hans]",
                    "max_length": 100
                },
                "serial_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape Number",
                    "max_length": 100
                },
                "shape_variant_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape Variant Number",
                    "max_length": 100
                },
                "collection": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Collection",
                    "max_length": 255
                },
                "qr_code": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "QR Code",
                    "max_length": 255
                },
                "extra_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Extra Number",
                    "max_length": 255
                },
                "art_numbers": {
                    "type": "field",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Art numbers"
                },
                "remark": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Remark",
                    "max_length": 400
                },
                "has_associated_product_variant": {
                    "type": "field",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": true,
                    "label": "Has associated product variant"
                },
                "shape_benchmark": {
                    "type": "nested object",
                    "required": false,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "label": "Shape benchmark",
                    "children": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "required": false,
                            "read_only": true,
                            "label": "ID"
                        },
                        "up_spin_speed": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "required": false,
                            "read_only": false,
                            "label": "Up Spin Speed",
                            "max_length": 15
                        },
```

Will add more details to this should i learn more

Answer (score 1):

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """
              add type for Related model
        """
        ret = OrderedDict()
        fields = [field for field in self.fields.values() if not field.write_only]

        for field in fields:
            try:
                key = field.get_attribute(instance)
            except SkipField:
                continue
            value = field.to_representation(key)
            if isinstance(field, ModelSerializer):
                value_type = {}
                for k, v in value.items():
                    value_type[k+'_type'] = type(v).__name__
                value.update(value_type)
            ret[field.field_name] = value

        for field in self.context:
            # context defaults to including 'request', 'view' and 'format' keys.
            if field not in ['request', 'view', 'format']:
                ret[field] = self.context[field]
        return ret
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'portrait', 'gender', 'tel', 'get_gender_display', 'get_full_name')


class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    from_user = UserListSerializer(read_only=True)
    to_user = UserListSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'
```

get url `http://192.168.1.108/message/3` i can get:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "from_user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "schoolms",
        "portrait": "http://192.168.1.108/media/default/user/default.png",
        "gender": 2,
        "tel": "",
        "get_gender_display": "x",
        "get_full_name": "schoolms",
        "tel_type": "str",
        "gender_type": "int",
        "id_type": "int",
        "get_full_name_type": "str",
        "portrait_type": "str",
        "get_gender_display_type": "str",
        "username_type": "str"
    },
    "to_user": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "x1",
        "portrait": "http://192.168.1.108/media/user/20171012-102543-778.png",
        "gender": 2,
        "tel": "",
        "get_gender_display": "x",
        "get_full_name": "x1",
        "tel_type": "str",
        "gender_type": "int",
        "id_type": "int",
        "get_full_name_type": "str",
        "portrait_type": "str",
        "get_gender_display_type": "str",
        "username_type": "str"
    },
    "subject": "x1",
    "content": "x2",
    "is_read": 0,
    "from_user_abandon": false,
    "to_user_abandon": false,
    "create_time": "2017-10-18 17:50:44",
    "update_time": "2017-10-18 17:50:44"
}
```

Comment: no, i want to know all the datatype for all the fields inside from_user and to_user

Comment: I have researched quite extensively. have you heard of drf-schema-adapter?

Comment: thanks for that. not sure if that's the best way to solve this issue. I really appreciate this alternative. i think i will experiment with drf-schema adapter. if that fails, i will try yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have decided to go with drf-schema-adapter. I prefer to reuse existing code libraries than to roll out my own