# How can I change the returned field metadata type in the json returned by OPTIONS using the Django REST Framework?

Tags: json, django, types, metadata

I am currently writing an automated script to extract metadata types from my models in Django endpoints which I am trying to hook up to swift.

[How to pass information about the field data type to the frontend when using Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217438/how-to-pass-information-about-the-field-data-type-to-the-frontend-when-using-dja)

The previous question on stack exchange explains how the OPTIONS field can be used to extract the metadata from my models; however, I run into a problem in that not all fields returned are detailed. Particularly, foreign key fields do not specify the correct metadata type.

for instance,

```
"created_by_merchant": {
"type": "field",
"required": false,
"read_only": true,
"label": "Created by merchant"
}

"item_size_selection": {
"type": "field",
"required": false,
"read_only": false,
"label": "Item size selection"
}
```

Both are foreign keys. Created by merchant should be an integer, item_size_selection should be a charfield. Is there any way I can specify the type for particular fields in my OPTIONS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around to the issue. Within serializers, one can specify foreign keys as their particular serializer field using source.

Here is an example:

```
created_by_merchant = serializers.IntegerField(source='created_by_merchant_id', read_only=True)
```

Not sure why I needed to add the read_only field again even though its specified in the meta class, but it requires matching there for it to work with read only.